# Double List Comprehension in Python?

Tags: python

I have a function that takes a list of tables from a database instance and returns the table's column names.

```
def list_columns(self):
    tables = self.list_tables()
    col_list = []
    for t in tables:
        for column in tables[t].columns:
            col_list.append(column)
    return col_list
```

This will return what we're looking for, which is the names of the columns

[Column('id', INTEGER(), table=, primary_key=True, nullable=False, server_default=DefaultClause(<sqlalchemy.sql.elements.TextClause object at 0x7f2d9a7ded68>, for_update=False)),

When I try to place this same code into a list comprehension like so:

```
def list_columns(self):
    tables = self.list_tables()
    col_list = [column for t in tables for column in tables[t].columns]
    return col_list
```

The `col_list` returned is not the same as in the first function.

When I rearrange the order of the list comprehension like this:

```
def list_columns(self):
    tables = self.list_tables()
    col_list = [column for column in tables[t].columns for t in tables]
    return col_list
```

There is an error on the second to last line `Unresolved reference 't'`

How can I write these two for loops in a list comprehension?

EDITED - thanks for the input, a closer look revealed there is a different output that is shown when using print():
There is something odd occurring with the print statement.

```
tables = self.list_tables()
col_list = []
for t in tables:
    for column in tables[t].columns:
        print(column)
```

This will print a list like:

```
image.id
image.owner_id
image.location
```

Which is what we're looking for.
However, when I append `column` to a list and then print out that list, I'd expect it to be the same as what we see above.

But this code:

```
        tables = self.list_tables()
        col_list = []
        for t in tables:
            for column in tables[t].columns:
                col_list.append(column)
        print(col_list)
```

Prints out something like this:

```
[Column('id', INTEGER(), table=<image>, primary_key=True, nullable=False, server_default=DefaultClause(<sqlalchemy.sql.elements.TextClause object at 0x7f12c60b1da0>, for_update=False)), Column('owner_id', UUID(), table=<image>, nullable=False), ]
```

Comment: The first way is the correct way.  I can't imagine a case where it differs from the code you're replacing, could you give an example of what the difference is?

Comment: Please Post sample output in each case to differentiate the things, since the first list comprehension is correct. It wont help anyone to answer properly. And question get flagged for low quality

Comment: @wim and @ Guarav, Thanks, I took a closer look and edited my question - I mistook a difference in the list comprehension for what is actually a difference between print each individual element in the for loops vs. appending each each element to a list and then printing that list. This is still strange to me - there shouldn't be a difference in this instance. Thanks!

Comment: `tables[t]` seems odd...shouldn't it be just `t`?

Comment: `tables[t]` does look odd, but when just using the `t`, there is an error: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'columns'`